# Using $exists with $redact with mongo aggregate?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am using the $redact operator:

```
{ $redact: {
    $cond: {
        "if": {
            "$lt": [ "$number1", "$number2" ],
        },
        "then": "$$KEEP",
        "else": "$$PRUNE"
    }
}}
```

I would like to `$and: [{$lt:["$number1, $number2"]}, {$exists:[$number3, 1]}]`, but I cannot get the $exist, or checking for null.

Comment: just use `$match`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want [`$ifNull`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/) as it is a "sort of" equivalent, with the added function of returning an alternate value where the field does not exist:

```js
{ "$redact": {
    "$cond": {
        "if": {
            "$and": [
               { "$lt": [ "$number1", "$number2" ] },
               { "$ifNull": [ "$number3", false ] }
            ]
        },
        "then": "$$KEEP",
        "else": "$$PRUNE"
    }
}}
```

So where the field exists the value of the field is returned, and this is basically the same as saying `true`( unless of course its value is actually `false` in which case, wrap with `$cond` ), or returns the alternate which has been supplied as `false`.

Comment: what about NOT exists?  If I want it to return true if $eq null, and false if it does exist.

Comment: @CSharpAtl  That is what `$ifNull` does. As I said if the value is not "truthy" from a positive return then wrap it in `$cond` with `$eq` so that the equal to null value returned emits `true`.

Comment: I was able to just $not it.  Thanks.